# I got an issue in using moment function in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I recently used moment function of js to vue.
But it's not working.
It is saying that moment is not defined.
I looked for a solution in here but any of them didn't work for me.
How can I use moment in nuxt?

```
<script>
import moment from "moment";
export default {
...
computed:{
    calendarWeekdays:function(){
        var n=moment.weekdays();
        return n.push(n.shift()),n;
    },
...
```

And the error I got is:

```
ERROR in ./components/DatePicker.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/DatePicker.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
```

Do I have to install moment npm?

Comment: yould you show us the code how you tried to make it work?

Comment: I added the code for reference

Comment: and what error does appear?

Comment: I wrote error that I got

Comment: ` return n.push(n.shift()),n;` thats invalid syntax

Comment: Thx, but what about the `moment` case?

Comment: What is your Nuxt version ?

Comment: version=>Nuxt 2.0.0

Answer (score 6):

From the error message you got, you would have some settings issues.
Please follow these steps:

- Install moment module:

  ```
  yarn add --dev @nuxtjs/moment # or npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/moment
  ```
- Edit **nuxt.config.js** file and declare the module there:

  ```
  export default {
    buildModules: [
      '@nuxtjs/moment'
    ]
  }
  ```

At this point, it is ready to be used:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ weekdays }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      weekdays: moment.weekdays()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to use moment as a function, like this "moment()".
So your code will be,

```html
<script>
import moment from "moment";
export default {
...
computed:{
    calendarWeekdays:function(){
        var n = moment().weekdays();
        return n.push(n.shift()),n;
    },
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to import the library like this:

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

You can find more detailed information in the [official docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/).